# need help. plz help me. i cannot install wordpress

Tags: conditional-tags

i cannot install wordpress. when i type localhost/my file name it showed -
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.56 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To help you troubleshoot, consider the following things to do:

1. **Check Apache and PHP Installation**: Make sure Apache and PHP are installed correctly on your system. If you're new to WordPress development, using tools like [LocalWP](https://localwp.com/) or [WAMP](https://www.wampserver.com/en/download-wampserver-64bits/) can simplify the setup process.
2. **Verify URL Structure**: Ensure that your URL points to the correct folder where you pasted the WordPress files. It should be in the format http://localhost/wordpress_folder and not to a specific file name or a zip file.